# Attribute Error Django using tweepy oauth

Tags: python, django, oauth, tweepy

I'm trying to set up oauth in Django using Tweepy. I am getting the following error.

> AttributeError at /auth/
>
> 'dict' object has no attribute 'key'

This occurs in the following code when I try to store the request token for later access when the user is forwarded to the callback url (http://localhost:8000/callback).

```
def auth(request):
    # start the OAuth process, set up a handler with our details
    oauth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, CALLBACK)
    # direct the user to the authentication url
    # if user is logged-in and authorized then transparently goto the callback URL
    try:
        auth_url = oauth.get_authorization_url()
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        return HttpResponse('error', status=500)
    # store the request token
    request.session['unauthed_token_tw'] = (oauth.request_token.key, oauth.request_token.secret) 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_url)
```

I am new to Python and Django, does this error mean that the oauth.request_token is null? Could it be a problem with my callback url? Do I need to forward port 8000? Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this line of code:

```
request.session['unauthed_token_tw'] = (oauth.request_token.key, oauth.request_token.secret)
```

to this:

```
request.session['unauthed_token_tw'] = oauth.request_token
```

... after reading this [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/auth_tutorial.html). And now it works!